# Tags [mathdotnet] and [mathnet] seem to be redundant

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I think that [mathdotnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathdotnet), [math.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math.net) and [mathnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathnet) are redundant and should be merged or made synonyms of each other.

The description of the 'mathnet' tag states that it is for Math.NET Numerics (which is actually only a sub-project) but I'm not sure if that distinction warrants its own tag. If so, the tag is badly named.

Comment: There is also [tag:math.net]! Three tags for the same thing!

Comment: Which tag should be the master?

Comment: @RobertHarvey my 2c -- the project calls itself "math.net" (see terminology on https://www.mathdotnet.com/) so I think that is the most logical one to use. They use "dot" in the hostname I imagine for technical reasons.

Comment: @RobertHarvey [tag:mathdotnet] is the oldest tag by years and is the URL of the website. It also has by far the most comprehensive tag wiki.

Comment: I can't synonymize to [tag:math.net].  There are too many instances of the other tags; the system will kick out my request. If we decide to synonymize to [tag:math.net], a CM would have to do it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I can go on a mini edit spree if that would help.

Comment: Related - it looks like the user doing all the retagging was just angling for a badge; they stopped right after they got to 500.

Comment: @TylerH: Well, if you can do the retagging, I'll go ahead and put the synonym in and move the Tag Wiki.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well there are no more [tag:math.net] questions. It will take me a while longer to go through [tag:mathnet] as there are twice as many questions. EDIT - NVM, looks like you nuked that one.

Comment: @TylerH: mathnet is now mathnet.numerics.

Comment: @TylerH: Any objection to making math.net the master?

Comment: @RobertHarvey If you mean renaming mathdotnet to math.net, then no I don't have any objections. But I don't have any experience in the tag, so I may not be the best person to ask.

Comment: Math.NET is the name of the opensource project.  mathdotnet.com is the name of the website.

Comment: Also just a point of clarification, math.net appears to be a family of libraries, of which math.net numerics is only one (see https://www.mathdotnet.com/)

Comment: @TylerH: Yes.  I think the most sensible thing to do is merge mathnet-numerics into math.net

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into a user adding [mathnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathnet), [math.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math.net) and [mathdotnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathdotnet) to questions, ensuring each has all three of these. Yes, they need to be synonymous.

Comment: Thanks to your comment / answer this has gained some energy after sitting for > 1 year :)

Comment: @DaveInCaz Your request wasn't ignored. There's just 200 or so other synonym requests out there still

Comment: @Machavity wow, good to know